# Complex Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I'm a CPA with lots of Excel experience, but can't seem to figure out an answer to this question (of my own). Is there a way to apply conditional formatting for the below example:

EXAMPLE: I have a formula that is =sum(B4,C28,A32,B40)---> Is there a way to apply conditional formatting rule on cells B4, C28, A32, and B40 that automatically highlights the cells being used in the formula?

^ this would help tremendously with a bank reconciliation I am performing. Instead of manually highlighting. There are many cells I would have to manually do this to. I'm a firm believer in being as automated as possible for reconciliations (in fact most of my recon is simply a drag and drop template I made that gets most of the recon items pinpointed automatically).

NOTE: Currently what I am doing is using =isformula(xxxxx) on the cells that I have to manually pair. Then highlighting to ensure all is captured/nothing missed.

Comment: I probably would consider another route, but in trying to directly answer your question use `=FORMULATEXT()` along with other string manipulation formulas in the conditional format rule.

Comment: What sort of route would you consider? Open to ideas! If you can give me a basic thought, I can probably get it from there.      Thanks a ton my friend!

Comment: @RyanHoyle,, `Trace Precedents` is the most easiest method finding or marking cells used in formula as it's also show below by #Teylyn but trap multiple formula can be executed by VBA macro,, is fastest one,, if you need a Macro please [Edit] your post and add new TAG  , `VBA`.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are building that formula as you are doing your reconciliation. If yes, then I would suggest a helper column with 1/0 for include/exclude the reconciliation row. Use a sumifs formula to get the total and conditional formatting based on the helper column. You may be tempted to try using solver with this setup, my experience is it's very slow...

Comment: You might consider building a UDF using Range.Precedents and Intersect but you will have to observe the restrictions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541342/when-called-from-an-excel-vba-udf-range-precedents-returns-the-range-and-not-it).

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like spreadsheet auditing. Excel has a few built-in tools to help with that.

You can use "Trace Precedents" on the Formulas ribbon to draw lines to cells that the current cell depends on. Use "Remove arrows" to remove the arrows.

[image]

Or you can use the Formula view by clicking "Show Formulas" on the Formulas ribbon (or use Ctrl+` -- that is the back tick to the left of the number 1 on a US keyboard). That will display the formulas in the cells instead of the results and any cell that is used in the formula will be highlighted.

[image]

Conditional formatting is not a good approach because you would have to apply the conditional formats to all cells in the spreadsheet. That would bring things to a crawl pretty drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `FORMULATEXT()` as the basis for this:

```
=IFERROR(FIND(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("ADDRESS",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))),"$",""),FORMULATEXT($C$1)),0)<>0
```

The above assumes you know the cell in which the formula you are examining resides. It uses $C$1 but of course you can change it to be any cell you wish.

You can create the conditional formatting ("CF") rule for any single cell **BUT do it while IN that cell:  while that cell is selected**, then copy the cell and paste formats to any other cell you wish to include in the CF.

I am picturing that you have the cell with the `SUM()` formula and are populating the cells it references directly. If you have a list you are typing somewhere, you can refer to it directly when making your CF formula.

The formula uses `ADDRESS()` to create a textual cell reference for whatever cell is selected and so whatever cells the CF is eventually laid over. Then it uses `INDIRECT()` to make that a "real" cell reference. Finally, it uses `SUBSTITUTE()` to remove the $'s (give you "A1" not $A$1").

That becomes the material for `FIND()` to look for in the `SUM()` function you are adding cells to. `FORMULATEXT()` is used to get the text of that formula and since "SUM(" and ")" are not part of any acceptable cell reference, nothing need be done about them and `FIND()` will just be searching amongst the cells referenced between the parentheses. `IFERROR` checks to see if it failed, giving 0 as a result if so because `FIND()` cannot produce a 0 result. That means you either get some positive integer, or 0 from this step.

Lastly, the CF checks that against being 0, and if it is NOT 0, it highlights the cell however you like.

This is part of a broader capability no one seems to be exploring. I can create Named Ranges that I can append `()` to and enter whatever I like inside the parentheses the same as arguments in a "real" function. A couple supporting Named Ranges then give me a Named Range that looks and acts like a function programmed into Excel, like `SUM()` is, with any arguments I choose. Favorites here for co-workers include `ourLOOKUP()` (company name, not "our") taking INDEX/MATCH arguments and putting them into a function built like `VLOOKUP()`.

SO UDF's essentially, without knowing VBA much or running into places where VBA is not allowed to be used.

Kinda b%st%rds to do the first time, and touchy, but nice.

But the above will handle your highlighting if you populate the `()` in your `SUM()` as I'm guessing. Doesn't extend the answer to addressing your larger task, just the highlighting you ask about.